# Editting start up code in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#

i have maybe a newbie question, but i have started course about c# maybe a week ago , and there we are using Visual studio, so every time we open a new project (Console application) there shows up an page with code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

and lectures want from us to remove some parts so the beginning code should like that :

```
using System;

class NameOfApp
{
    static void Main()
    {

    }
}
```

my question is : Is there a way to remove those parts somewhere from the menu  ?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing that will automatically make all the changes your lecturer wants.

What you can do instead is create your own template for a new project and use that template.

This is a large subject - start reading about it on [Visual Studio Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky.aspx) on MSDN - [customizing an existing template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247119.aspx) is probably the easiest way to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new project template for Visual Studio like Oded suggested, but you could also just delete template code you don't want and replace it with what the lecturers want.